# Is it ok to feed a puppy just once a day?

Tags: dogs, health, diet

There are three 4 months old stray puppies in my area and I feed every one of them 100gms of kibbles just once a day(10pm-11pm) as I dont get time.
So do kibbles get digested just like normal food or they simply get converted into poop and get wasted?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have two different questions here.

> Does kibbles get digested just like normal food or they simply get converted into poop and get wasted?

A don't know what is normal food. However millions of dogs, young puppies and older dogs, are fed kibble everyday and that's definitely digested and that's providing them a very decent source of nutrients. It is also true that part of it is "converted into poop".

So feeding puppies kibble is overall a quite good idea.

I know that there is a debate "kibble vs raw meat vs bones vs you-name-it" but that's a separate question.

> Is it OK to feed a puppy just once a day

As these are stray pups that's in any case better than nothing.

The reasoning is that puppies shouldn't ingest the totally of their recommended amount of food in one go. Even if they would possibly eat it all that's quite a lot. So it is recommended that pups under 6 m/o be fed 3 times a day or a least twice a day.

Here is a quote from [Dr. Kristy Conn](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kristy_Conn):

> Puppies should be fed three to four times a day [...]
>   Smaller meals are easier to digest for the puppy and energy levels don’t peak and fall so much with frequent meals. At around six months you may start feeding twice a day for convenience but because your dog is a mixed large breed dog I would recommend sticking with a 3-4 times a day feeding schedule if possible to minimize the risk of gastric dilatation volvulus.

Comment: I meant to say that do the food I give to the puppies gets digested normally or simply gets converted into poop without absorbing the nutrients as I feed at late night(before they go to sleep) and as also its just a one time meal...